# Compiling Tor on Windows, what is needed?

Tags: windows, source-code, platform

The current stable version of Tor, 0.2.3.25 works well on Win98/ME/2000. The present 0.2.4 versions require XP or newer. I'd like to compile the 0.2.4 versions to run on Win98 through Win 2000. What do I need to compile Tor on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I built it, I got the [mingw32 toolchain](http://msysgit.github.io/), and then started building the libraries needed.

On [our continuous integreation setup](https://jenkins.torproject.org/) the Tor build for Win32 [pulls in the builds for](https://gitweb.torproject.org/project/jenkins/jobs.git/blob/07532d43880a086e9428e2948276c33b0f8552f4:/jobs.yaml#l217) for libevent, openssl, and zlib.
The [build scripts](https://gitweb.torproject.org/project/jenkins/tools.git/tree/HEAD:/slaves/windows) we use there might be helpful.

I found [Erinn's scripts to build the Tor Browser Bundle](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/tree/HEAD:/build-scripts) helpful when I set up our Jenkins, but it was tough going.

Comment: I was wondering if you're able to enable WebRTC in TOR if you mingle with settings/configurations before compiling it. Would you happen to know?