# how to build tor on windows using visual studio?

Tags: configuration, build

> how to build tor which is a c project in visual studio c++? How to import tor source code?

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask this question at https://stackoverflow.com or research there if it was already asked.

Comment: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/610/compiling-tor-on-windows-what-is-needed I think this covers it. Importing the source code would be in the documentation of visual studio, not really Tor related